# What does spontaneous mean in term of forward and reverse reactions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-control

I just learnt about Gibb's Free Energy and was thinking about an exothermic reaction with a negative change in entropy. This means that the reaction would occur at low temperatures. But that means that if the system the reaction is taking place in has heat removed from it the reaction would occur. I am not sure if this next assumption is true or not, but if the reaction is not happening that means the rate of reaction is negative (rate being defined as Δ[Product]/Δtime). Since the rate is also defined as R = k[reactants], and concentration cannot be negative, this means that k must be negative, and also that k increases when temperature decreases. However this violates the Arrhenius equation, where an increase in temperature results in an increase in the rate constant. The only solution I see to this conundrum is my assumption was wrong and maybe spontaneous just means the rate of reverse reaction>rate of forward reaction, so they both have positive values for k. I wanted clarification if this was correct or not, or if I completely messed up the definition of Gibb's Free Energy in the first place.

Comment: The net reaction rate is zero when the reaction is not happening, since the concentration of all species is constant. Both forward and reverse rates occur, and it is possible to write rate equations such that rate constants are only positive. What changes when you are not at equilibrium is that either forward or reverse rate is larger.

Comment: If it's true in the forward direction, it's also true in the backwards direction. The magnitude of those changes may be different which is why there is ultimately a dependence on temperature, at least in the case you're describing.

Comment: I think you should re-frame your third sentence which is not clear. Other than that (i) If the reaction is not happening, than Δ[Product] is zero, thus, rate of reaction is zero. (ii) Value of rate constant can never be negative. (iii) Value of $k$ increases with temperature for both exothermic and endothermic reactions but for exothermic reactions, the rate of backward reaction will increase with increase in $T$.